# How to run debugger on a function with no error?

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio

Rstudio's debugger is pretty great for functions that fall apart. I am working with a very long function that does not throw errors but throws thousands of warnings which I believe are causing a slow-down. I'd like to find the source of these warnings.

Is there any way to run a function with a debugger to step into the function and run line-by-line using all the argument defaults, environments, and such which are automatically generated in the function using things like `match.call` and such?

Comment: U can use try and throw method to check part of function to find the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `browser()` wherever you want to jump into your function and gain line by line execution with the ability to examine the environment.

The shortcuts for using it can be found in the corresponding help page `?browser`

A small fake example session of how one might use browser...

```
> z <- 4
> 
> foo <- function(){
+   x <- 2
+   browser()
+   y <- 3
+   answer <- x+z
+   return(answer)
+ }
> foo()
Called from: foo()
Browse[1]> ls() # we can use ls() to see what is defined
[1] "x"
Browse[1]> x # we can then examine what is stored in the variables
[1] 2
Browse[1]> n # n tells it to run the next line
debug at #4: y <- 3
Browse[2]> n
debug at #5: answer <- x + z
Browse[2]> y
[1] 3
Browse[2]> ls()
[1] "x" "y"
Browse[2]> n
debug at #6: return(answer)
Browse[2]> ls()
[1] "answer" "x"      "y"     
Browse[2]> answer
[1] 6
Browse[2]> x+y
[1] 5
Browse[2]> # oh I defined answer with z instead of y
Browse[2]> # let's go change the function
Browse[2]> Q # exit the browser
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `debug` or `debugonce` (for debugging only once).  Just `debug(yourFunctionName)`.

Don't forget to `undebug` after you are done.

I believe that `browser` is a good option for you, since you can change the points that the debugging mode starts.

Comment: This is also a good recommendation if you don't want to manually place the  breakpoints and then try to remember to remove them.  In the case where you are only going to debug once there is the handy `debugonce` function which will remove the debugging stuff after the first time you run it for you so you don't need to remember to `undebug`.